# How to use v-for on a 2 dimensional array

Tags: arrays, vue.js

I want to loop through a 2 dimensional array with Vue.js, but when I use a nested `v-for` inside another `v-for`, I get this error:

> - invalid v-for alias "case" in expression: v-for="case in line"

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    chessboard: [
      [null,null,null,null],
      [null,null,null,null],
      [null,null,null,null],
      [null,null,null,null]
    ]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="chessboard">
    <div v-for="line in chessboard">
      <div v-for="case in line">
        <button></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How should I do to make it work?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: case is a reserved word, try changing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`case` is a reserved word :) 
(switch-case)

https://jsfiddle.net/3k8dghvo/

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="chessboard">
    <div v-for="line in chessboard">
      <div v-for="cell in line">
        <button></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```